# while(!((str[i]>='0'&&str[i]<='9')||str[i]=='\0')) как перевести на человеческий язык это условие?

Tags: c, условия, логические-выражения

```
while(!((str[i]>='0'&&str[i]<='9')||str[i]=='\0'))
```

Как работает это условие? Как я понимаю, это значит «выполнять тело цикла, *пока `str[i]` не равно числовому символу или `str[i]` не равно нуль-терминатору*». Но это неверно, ведь если бы это было верно, то условие

```
while(!((str[i]>='0'&&str[i]<='9')||str[i]=='\0'))
```

и условие

```
while(!(str[i]>='0'&&str[i]<='9')||str[i]!='\0')
```

были бы одинаковы, но они выполняются по разному.

Comment: Сначала внесите отрицание внутрь скобок (не забываем, что || при этом поменяется на &&), потом уже проще будет понять.

Comment: Да, это полезно знать: [Законы де Моргана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Законы_де_Моргана)

Comment: Как я понимаю, это значит «выполнять тело цикла, пока str[i] не равно числовому символу или str[i] не равно нуль-терминатору». -Неверно понимаете. Это значит "выполнять тело цикла до тех пор, ПОКА НЕ (str[i] равно числовому символу или str[i] равно нуль-терминатору) " Вы поторопились раскидать отрицание по двум частям условия.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала советую сделать код чуть более читаемым, добавив отступы между операторами:

```
while(!((str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') || str[i] == '\0'))
```

Теперь внесем отрицание внутрь, применив один из законов де Моргана:

```
НЕ (a ИЛИ b) = (НЕ a) И (НЕ b)
```

Получаем:

```
while((str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9') && str[i] != '\0')
```

Для более легкого восприятия можно заменить `str[i]` на `C` (*character*):

```
while((C < '0' || C > '9') && C != '\0')
```

Первый операнд логического И, проверяет, что `C` не является цифрой, второй — что `C` не является нуль-терминатором. Получается, что условие будет истинно, когда `C` — не цифра и не нуль-терминатор.

---

В стандартной библиотеке языка C есть специальная функция [`isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/), которая проверяет, является ли символ цифрой. При ее использовании условие становится гораздо более очевидным:

```
while(!isdigit(C) && C != '\0')
```